# Unknown Error Creating a certificate

Tags: macos, gdb

I'm trying to install gdb for my mac.  I've followed the instructions [here](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/), but when I get to the step where I set the keychain to `system`, I get an error when I try to create it.  [image: picture]

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have a hunch this can happen when the cert already exists and the name conflicts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed it.  Instead of creating it for `system`, I created it for `login`. Then, I dragged the certificate into `system`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlock the System keychain first, then it works. Go to Keychain Access, right click on System and unlock.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I unlocked the system keychain and still got the same error.